# Prove that $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,....,x_n)$ is not symmetric function for $n>4$

Tags: functions

$\alpha _n ^n-1=0$

$\alpha _n=e^{2 \pi i/n}$

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1+\alpha _n x_2+ \alpha _n ^2 x_3+\cdots+\alpha _n ^{n-1} x_n)^n$$
 Prove that  $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)$ is not symmetric function for $n>4$

---

for example
 $n=2$

$\alpha _2=e^{2 \pi i/2}=-1$

$$f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+\alpha _2 x_2)^2=(x_1-x_2)^2=x_1 ^2 + x_2 ^2 -2 x_1 \cdot x_2$$

$$f(x_1,x_2)=f(x_2,x_1)=x_1 ^2 + x_2 ^2 -2 x_1 \cdot x_2$$

Therefore, for $n=2$, $f$ is a symmetric function

---

I noticed such functions while working on the proof of [Abel–Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem). The theorem shows that there is no general algebraic solution—that is, solution in radicals— to polynomial equations of degree five or higher . In [the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262661829), I also noticed symmetric functions definitions. This function has a key role for showing that there is no general algebraic solution—that is, solution in radicals— to polynomial equations of degree five or higher.

I would like to learn how to prove that $n>4$ the 
$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)$ is not symmetric function without using group theory because I am new learner in the subject. If possible please show  in similiar way as I shew for $n=2$.

Thanks for answers and your time.

---

EDIT: After asking the question, I have noticed one property for the function. I wanted to share it.

$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)= (x_1+\alpha _n x_2+ \alpha _n ^2 x_3+\cdots+\alpha _n ^{n-1} x_n)^n= $
$$=\alpha _n ^{n}(x_1+\alpha _n x_2+ \alpha _n ^2 x_3+\cdots+\alpha _n ^{n-1} x_n)^n=(x_n+\alpha _n x_1+ \alpha _n ^2 x_2+\cdots+\alpha _n ^{n-1} x_{n-1})^n=\alpha _n ^{n}(x_n+\alpha _n x_1+ \alpha _n ^2 x_2+\cdots+\alpha _n ^{n-1} x_{n-1})^n=(x_{n-1}+\alpha _n x_n+ \alpha _n ^2 x_1+\cdots+\alpha _n ^{n-2} x_{n-2})^n=....$$  If do this steps n times we will get same function in the begining, Thus

$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_n,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1})=f(x_{n-1},x_n,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-2})=.....=f(x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots,x_n,x_1)$
 (totally $n$ permutation of f is equal each other)

but Total permutation of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)$ is $n!$

I can see that only for n=2 the permutations are equal. So I need to extend the statement for n>2 .. And also  $Generic Human$ got same result with different approach .  Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I think you can prove it by showing that $f(x_1,x_2,0,0,...,0)\neq f(x_2,x_1,0,0,...,0)$ using much the same proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is symmetric.
\begin{aligned}
f(1,x,0,...,0)&= (1+\alpha_n x)^n \\
=f(x,1,0,...,0)&= (x+\alpha_n)^n \\
&= (1+\alpha_n^{-1} x)^n
\end{aligned}

This is a smooth function, so we can compute the derivative with respect to $x$ at $x=0$:
$$n\alpha_n = n\alpha_n^{-1}$$
This implies that either $n=0$ or $\alpha_n^2 = 1$, that is $n \leq 2$. So the theorem is actually true for all $n > 2$.